# Change the value of an <select> on grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the `<g:select>` on my proyect who is a one-to-many relation, 
but I want it to show the name (attribute) of my class instead of the id.

It shows something like this:

```
com.petshop.Category: 1
```

This is the code I use on the view:

```
<g:select id="subcategory" name="subcategory.id" from="${com.petshop.Category.list()}" optionKey="id"
          required="" value="${animalInstance?.category?.id}"/>
```

What should I change/add/delete to show "`Birs`" for instance, instead of "`com.petshop.Category: 1`" that is the id of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
<g:select id="subcategory" name="subcategory.name" from="${com.petshop.Category.list()*.name}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name"
              required="" value="${animalInstance?.category?.name}"/>
```

Comment: `<g:select id="category" name="category.id" from="${edu.upb.petshop.Category.list()}" optionValue="name" optionKey="id" required="" value="${subcategoryInstance?.category?.name}" />`

Comment: This is the solution, but your answer made get to it. Thanks

Comment: @user2350850 Do you have a `toString()` implementation in `Category` to return `name`?